# Expression expected Error in TS/graphql @ObjectType

Tags: typescript, graphql

I am getting this error that I do not understand, and cannot find anything on the internet explaining it. When I remove that object, the next object (@...) triggers the same error.. I think it has to do with the @, please share a link if anyone has any reading material about @.

```
  x Expression expected
   ,-[C:\Users\meowt\OneDrive\Desktop\2023next\next-gql-dogs\pages\api\graphql.ts:2:1]
 2 | import "reflect-metadata";
 3 | import { buildSchema, Resolver, Query, Arg, ObjectType, Field, ID } from "type-graphql";
 4 | 
 5 | @ObjectType()
   : ^
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The @ is just a typescript decorator. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html

As for the error, I get this quite often, at when setting things up or adjusting configurations. It always gets me in Next and I have hit a few times in other stacks.

The first fix is just a just a matter of restarting the build for me.
I am assuming you had tried this? It is annoying, but it has to do with the runtime having to run the configuration as it launches.

The second fix, is somewhat baffling to me. I sometimes get this same feedback from the lsp, and it is a bit of a read hearing. The thing throwing off typescript can very well be a property is not initialized with a value. To address this, either give it a default value or set "strictPropertyInitialization": false in your TS config!